# Getting Object Reference Not set Error in SMTP mail.send() C#.net core API project while using memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, smtp, memorystream

I have a .docx template with some dynamic display strings defined in it like below

```
 {{FirstName}}, {{ContactNumber}}",{{EmailId}}
```

Now i need to read this .docx file and need to replace this above texts with its equalent texts and
need to send that doc as attachment to the user. This is what i am trying to achieve.

So far i written code like this

```
 string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
 content.Replace("{{FirstName}}", objUser.FirstName);
 content.Replace("{{ContactNumber}}", objUser.Contact);
 content.Replace("{{EmailId}}", objUser.EmailId);

 var stream = new MemoryStream();
 var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

 writer.WriteLine(content);
 writer.Flush();

 stream.Position = 0;

 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
  {
      client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
      client.Port = 25;

      using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage())
      {
          System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new 
          
  
System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
          var coverAttachment = new Attachment(stream, contentType);
          coverAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "CoverLetter.pdf";
          emailMessage.Attachments.Add(coverAttachment);

         emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(value.toemail));
                            emailMessage.CC.Add(new 
         MailAddress("My To Address"));
         emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]);
         emailMessage.Subject = value.subject;
         emailMessage.Body = message;
         emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
         emailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
         emailMessage.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
         emailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
         emailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]));
```

//And before calling client.send()

i have a code like

```
client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                client.Dispose();
                                emailMessage.Dispose();
                                writer.Dispose();
                            };
```

Is there is anything i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

1. if you have created SmtpClient and MailMessage objects in "using" block, it would automatically call the Dispose methods on these objects. You don't need to call them yourselves.
2. SendCompleted event occurs when an asynchronous email send operation completes.
   You should probably use SendAsync() instead of Send()

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hi When i use SendAsync() i was getting timeout error.

Comment: Hey, I tried both Send() and SendAsync() (SendAsync() without the using blocks) and it worked fine for me. Can you check your attachment size or maybe try using a different SMTP server?

Comment: For SendAsynch UserToken i can pass it as NULL right if not applicable? Also i can use SendMailAsync too right for this?

Comment: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'
This is what i am getting

Comment: @NidhinPaul - Yes, I tried with NULL as user token. Did any one of Send() or SendAsync() worked for you? And, can you share code for SendMailAsync that you are using.

Comment: Hi Jain, yes as you suggested i removed the using and moved to SendEmailAsync() and used the event to dispose the objects. Now everything looks working....:)