# PDF file is not get generating properly in C# .net core project from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, memorystream

I have below code to create a pdf file

To read contents i used

```
String path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
                        +Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "Templates"
                          + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + 
                             "CoverLetter.docx";

string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.WriteLine(content);
writer.Flush();
                        
stream.Position = 0;
```

And then to write content i used

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\nithinpaul\Documents\Testing\test.pdf", 
FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        byte[] content1 = stream.ToArray();
                        file.Write(content1, 0, (int)content1.Length);

                        //byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                        //stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                        //file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
```

Pdf is generated in my local disk but when i try to open it its showing like something went wrong. and when i try to open it using notepad the content look like below. Any idea?

[image]

And in my .docx i have some texts like this

```
Application Number – {{AppNumber}}
First Name: {{FirstName}}
Contact Number: {{ContactNumber}}
Email Id: {{EmailId}}
```

Comment: Where are you actually doing the conversion to PDF?

Comment: Hi Ryan, in my .docx file i have a template with some texts and after reading it i do some replacments of texts and then tryig to save as pdf. So right now simply putting file extention as .pdf is what i am doing. Anything else do i need to do, Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Actually this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387583/getting-object-reference-not-set-error-in-smtp-mail-send-c-net-core-api-proje  is what i am trying to acheive

Comment: You can't just put a pdf extension on a file and expect it to be a pdf. There is a specific format it must conform to. There are libraries that can convert between file formats if you want to research them.

Comment: Crowcoder is right, simply changing the extension is not enough. They are fundamentally different formats. Conversion is not as easy as it sounds. If you are just using this to produce a document then there are some libraries that can help you create a document from scratch. Or you will need to read word document using a proper library, replace the text and then convert the output to PDF.

Comment: CrowCoder/Ryan I changed my source template to a .pdf file and put my contents ther, after using the above code no contents displaying now in my generated pdf file. But i can see there is 2 pages as i expected. Any idea

Comment: First of all, @Crowcoder of course is right that by changing the extension you don't convert. But there is another issue in your code, when it *reads contents*, it loads the _binary_ docx file as a _string_. Doing so can damage the data beyond repair. Thus, most likely your code reads a valid docx file and then saves a broken docx file with an inappropriate file extension.

Comment: Hi mk, the reason was loading the file as text is to replace the text so if i am loading it as binary itself can i replace its contents like my requirement? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From our discussion in the comments, what I believe you are trying to achieve is the following.

1. Open a Word Document
2. Replace some values in said word document
3. Save the document as a PDF file.

To do this we will make use of a Nuget Package called FreeSpire.Doc, please note there are a number of alternative packages that will do the same thing and I suggest you do some research into which suits your requirements the most as free versions have limitations. You also probably want to avoid having a dependency on Microsoft Office.

Anyway, this code will achieve what you want with FreeSpire.Doc

```
//Open the template document    
var doc = new Document("PathToTemplate.docx");
//Replace the values
doc.Replace("{{AppNumber}}", "AppNumberValue", true, true);
doc.Replace("{{FirstName}}", "FirstNameValue", true, true);
doc.Replace("{{ContactNumber}}", "ContactNumberValue", true, true);
doc.Replace("{{EmailId}}", "EmailIdValue", true, true);
//Save the document as a PDF file.
doc.SaveToFile("templateConverted.pdf", FileFormat.PDF);
```

Don't forget the using statement for the Nuget package.

```
using Spire.Doc;
```

You can also use the SaveToStream method to save the document to a Stream instead of a File. The Document also supports a constructor that will accept a Steam.

Comment: OK Ryan I will try as you said, Correction in your 3rd point . My actual requirement is after replacing the text with my DB value, i need to send this stream value as attachment to users(No need to keep hard copy in my local disk). So like you mentioned i will try with Savetostream. 
Also Ryan, Without using any of this dlls can i achieve this only using memory stream?
Thanks

Comment: If you need help reading the values from the database, or creating and sending the email, then you should raise these as separate questions. You could use the Microsoft Office interop to do something similar, but this would require Office being installed on the machine. (Not suitable for things like Azure App Service) but in plain raw C# there is not easy conversion, hence why these packages can be very expensive.